# tex document creat tex document with special content

Tags: macros, write, write-file

I want a *.tex document that create a *.tex that content the following lines:

```
\newread\NoFile

\newcounter{AME}

\openin\NoFile=V/AME.txt

\read\NoFile to \AME

\closein\NoFile
```

so I looked up in the internet and come up with this:

```
\newwrite\file

\immediate\openout\file=myfilename.tex  
    \immediate\write\file{\newread\NoFile}

    \immediate\write\file{\newcounter{AME}}
    \immediate\write\file{\openin\NoFile=V/AME.txt}
    \immediate\write\file{\read\NoFile to \AME}
    \immediate\write\file{\closein\NoFile}
\closeout\file
```

But the problem its not giving the information in the way it should.
I don't know how to solve

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Can you please edit your question and describe a little bit more, what you expect, and what happens instead? If useful, you can alos provide screenshots. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file

```
\newwrite\file

\immediate\openout\file=myfilename.tex  
    \immediate\write\file{\newread\NoFile}

    \immediate\write\file{\newcounter{AME}}
    \immediate\write\file{\openin\NoFile=V/AME.txt}
    \immediate\write\file{\read\NoFile to \AME}
    \immediate\write\file{\closein\NoFile}
\closeout\file


\stop
```

produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \NoFile 
                   
l.4     \immediate\write\file{\newread\NoFile}
```

as `\Nofile` is not defined at that point, you can suppress its attempted expansion using `\string` so this runs without error

```
\newwrite\file

\immediate\openout\file=myfilename.tex  
    \immediate\write\file{\string\newread\string\NoFile}

    \immediate\write\file{\string\newcounter{AME}}
    \immediate\write\file{\openin\string\NoFile=V/AME.txt}
    \immediate\write\file{\read\noexpand\NoFile to \string\AME}
    \immediate\write\file{\closein\string\NoFile}
\closeout\file


\stop
```

leaving `myfilename.tex`containing

```
\newread\NoFile
\newcounter{AME}
\openin \NoFile=V/AME.txt
\read \NoFile to \AME
\closein \NoFile
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i try to use the filename.tex in another *.tex through. \inpute put it don't work. Maybe because of spaces ?

Comment: @IHPro sorry try now (changed one \string to \noexpand so it keeps a space before `to`

Comment: Awesome,Thank you very much.                                                             \newread\NoFile
\newcounter{AME}
\openin \NoFile=V/AME.txt
\read \NoFile to \AME
\closein \NoFile                                                                                                                                This is the content but I can't use it in another *.tex probably because of the spaces. have can I remove them?

Comment: @IHPro that file should input without error. If you get an error make a real example and post a new questipn

Comment: I am sorry you are right. Thank you very much. That was really helpful :)

Comment: `\write{\unexpanded{...}}` can also be used